# What would you call the scheduled event within a bigger event?

Tags: word-choice

What would you call the scheduled events within a bigger event? A general word that could be used in both examples below.

**Examples:**

1. you have a the festival of apples and at 2 there will be apple
   picking and at 3 there will be cider making.
2. you have a the conference and multiple speakers.

**Update:**

After looking for an answer and not finding one I am 100% happy with I have listed a few options that I feel are close to an acceptable answer below.

- Itinerary
- Agenda
- Activity

Comment: These are activities at the big event.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin - Sorry I added another example. Activities would work for the first example but not the second example I added.

Comment: You have speakers scheduled for _presentations_.  Note you show 'a the' in each example, where 'a' is probably enough. If you need a general term, use _time slots_: At the festival, there are time slots at 2:00 for apple picking and 3:00 for cider making. At the conference, there are time slots for multiple speakers.

Comment: Presentations, activities, or sessions.

Comment: itinerary or agenda may work here. What would you call an itinerary item?

Answer (score 1):

When a conference consists of multiple sub-events which all members are expected to attend together, these are often called plenary sessions. So a  Festival of Apples could have several plenary sessions one after the other on topics such as Recent Developments in Peeling Techniques, Orchard Management for Dummies, The Future of the Granny Smith, Red or Green for Pies and so on.

Events other than these such as Apple Picking and Cider Making may be called Fringe Events - they are not essential parts of the main conference and not everyone is expected to attend.

Another type of event is the Breakout Session. Generally these take place on various subjects simultaneously and people are expected to go to one or another of them depending on their particular interests or expertise. There might be one on Choosing Manure which apple growers might attend while simultaneously another session took place on Selecting Pastry which apple pie makers attended.

A less-used alternative to Plenary Session is Core Session, which might be particularly apt for an Apple Conference.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks you for the answer. Still I am trying to find a single word to describe this. There may not be one.

Answer (score -2):

See **epicycle** at [MERRIAM WEBSTER](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epicycle) defined as

> a process going on within a larger one.

Comment: Technically that is correct. I was hoping for a more user friendly word lol.

Comment: Agreed, epicycle has a very specific astronomical meaning, and you'd be hard pressed to find usage of that word outside the field.

Comment: @user262430 Yes, but sometimes that is not possible.